# Minizinc: partial search strategy with sharing indexes

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

Given 3 vectors variables of the same length (let's say A, B, and C), is there a way in Minizinc to apply a search strategy on one of them(let's say B), and at each variable of B instantiated, the search goes to the variables in the same position in A and C?

E.g: `A =[a1,a2,a3], B=[b1,b2,b3], C=[c1,c2,c3]`

I want a search like this:

1. search on B with some criteria (e.g: first fail, to be sure that we're not going in order)
2. find the next variable to assign (b2)
3. assign values to a2 and c2 (same position/same index of b2)
4. continue the search on B etc...

Answer (score 1):

Complex search heuristics are generally not supported in MiniZinc in general. However, your description of the search might be close to priority search: a search mechanism published for the Chuffed solver.
You can find a description of priority search in the following workshop paper: https://ozgurakgun.github.io/ModRef2017/files/ModRef2017_PrioritySearchWithMiniZinc.pdf